# I have a math problem and I love stackoverflow

Tags: math, geometry

I know it's not programming question but I thought we could all use the challenge :)

[Link to diagram](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4185850/IMG00071-20100923-2108.jpg)

Point A is the source of a laser.  It is shinned at a single mirror and then reflected to another mirror finally arriving at point B ... see picture.

The goal is to find the total distance of all the lines.

I am not a student and this is not homework.

Comment: You know... there's a Math Stack Exchange site. Perhaps this question would be better suited there? http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Same as a straight line from (-x, y) to (a, -b).

sqrt((a+x)^2 + (b+y)^2)